# How can I load multiple web pages and switch between them?

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried setting up a segmented control to load the different web pages and switch through them but that didn't work. Is there a way that I can easily add more url's and be able to switch between them all? I am wanting to load about 10 in total.

***EDIT: I have changed my approach and still cannot seem to find a way to select different pages once it has loaded. It is showing the build is successful and I am not receiving any errors. How can I enable the functionality to switch between all of the web pages?***

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewA: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewB: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewC: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewD: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewE: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewF: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewG: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewH: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewI: WKWebView!
    
    let urlA: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taraxacum"
    let urlB: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear"
    let urlC: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerophyllum_tenax"
    let urlD: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant"
    let urlE: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibiscus"
    let urlF: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion"
    let urlG: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_panda"
    let urlH: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin"
    let urlI: String = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf"
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        let myURLA = URL(string: urlA)
        let myURLB = URL(string: urlB)
        let myURLC = URL(string: urlC)
        let myURLD = URL(string: urlD)
        let myURLE = URL(string: urlE)
        let myURLF = URL(string: urlF)
        let myURLG = URL(string: urlG)
        let myURLH = URL(string: urlH)
        let myURLI = URL(string: urlI)
       
        let myRequestA = URLRequest(url: myURLA!)
        let myRequestB = URLRequest(url: myURLB!)
        let myRequestC = URLRequest(url: myURLC!)
        let myRequestD = URLRequest(url: myURLD!)
        let myRequestE = URLRequest(url: myURLE!)
        let myRequestF = URLRequest(url: myURLF!)
        let myRequestG = URLRequest(url: myURLH!)
        let myRequestH = URLRequest(url: myURLH!)
        let myRequestI = URLRequest(url: myURLI!)
       
        webViewA.load(myRequestA)
        webViewB.load(myRequestB)
        webViewC.load(myRequestC)
        webViewD.load(myRequestD)
        webViewE.load(myRequestE)
        webViewF.load(myRequestF)
        webViewG.load(myRequestG)
        webViewH.load(myRequestH)
        webViewI.load(myRequestI)
       
        webViewA.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webViewB.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webViewC.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webViewD.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webViewE.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webViewF.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webViewG.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webViewH.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webViewI.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? In what specific way didn't it work?

Comment: When I just added in more url's the same way that I have the one in my post only the first one loaded.

Comment: If you just stack the webviews on top of each other you will only be able to see the top one. You need to think about how you want to navigate between those views

Answer (score 0):

You are calling load method multiple times on webViewB instance.

```
webViewA.load(myRequestA)
webViewB.load(myRequestB)
webViewB.load(myRequestC)
webViewB.load(myRequestD)
webViewB.load(myRequestE)
webViewB.load(myRequestF)
webViewB.load(myRequestG)
webViewB.load(myRequestH)
webViewB.load(myRequestI)
```

Comment: I fixed that issue. I am wanting to display the WebViews all fullscreen so they are all stacked on top of each other. Is there a way that I can switch between all of them with what I have now or will I need to add another function?

Comment: in ypur storybard is webViewA.. webViewI in StackView?